# Selective aggregation with filter | Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose in an index I have list of documents like these

```
{"uid": 1, "stage": "A", "value": "X"}
{"uid": 1, "stage": "B", "value": "X"}
{"uid": 1, "stage": "C", "value": "X"}

{"uid": 2, "stage": "A", "value": "X"}
{"uid": 2, "stage": "B", "value": "X"}

{"uid": 3, "stage": "B", "value": "X"}
{"uid": 3, "stage": "C", "value": "X"}
```

Now for value X if I want to check how many got to stage `C` and how many were in stage `A` I can easily do that. But in certain error scenarios - stage `A` is not captured but the last stage `C` is captured. I want to discard any such scenarios where the last stage is captured and previous stages are not. If the last stage - stage `C` is captured then it has to have `A` and `B` as well - if not then don't include them in the count of total `C`.

Tried all kinds of different aggs and filter but not getting the exact thing.
Note: Before querying elasticsearch I would definitely have the list of `stages` beforehand for the given index.

Example: If I run the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "value": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stages": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "stage.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response would be:

```
{
  "took": 180,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "value": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "X",
          "doc_count": 7,
          "stages": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "B",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "A",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "C",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here the `doc_count` of `C` is 2 but I want it to be 1 because for uid - 3 there is no stage `A` so `uid` `3` never started with `A` - I want to discard this result.

Comment: Please add a result sample showing what you're expecting

Comment: @KevinQuinzel Sure. Updated the question. Added a sample query and response.